# Cannot borrow as immutable because it also borrowed as mutable

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I have the following minimal example to reproduce this issue:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut vec = Vec::from(["Hello"]);
    let mut some_struct = SomeStruct { field: "World" };
    some_struct.doSomething(&mut vec);
    
    println!("{:?}", vec);
}

struct SomeStruct<'a> {
    field: &'a str
}

impl<'a> SomeStruct<'a> {
    fn doSomething(&mut self, vec: &'a mut Vec<&'a str>) {
        vec.push(self.field);
    }
}
```

(obviously, `doSomething` doesn't need to take a mutable reference to self in this example, but I do need a mutable reference in the original code)

When I run the above example, I get the following errror:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `vec` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:22:22
   |
20 |     some_struct.doSomething(&mut vec);
   |                             -------- mutable borrow occurs here
21 |
22 |     println!("{:?}", vec);
   |                      ^^^
   |                      |
   |                      immutable borrow occurs here
   |                      mutable borrow later used here
   |
   = note: this error originates in the macro `$crate::format_args_nl` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

How can I print out the `vec` after it being borrowed mutably by `doSomething`?

I've tried cloning `vec`, `RefCell`, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `&'a mut Vec<...>`. Repeating lifetimes is often wrong. In this case, you tell Rust "I want to borrow `vec` for `'a`". But `'a` is determined by `self.field`, and is inferred to be `'static` here (or not; it doesn't really matter. The most important part is that it is inferred to be longer/equal to the lifetime of `self`, because otherwise `self` would hold a dangling reference). Now, by borrowing `vec` for `'a`, you prevent use of it at least until `self` is destroyed.

If you remove the `'a` lifetime from `vec`, [it works](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e08e8cec34ae623cd27aa18949ef9df1):

```rust
fn doSomething(&mut self, vec: &mut Vec<&'a str>) {
    vec.push(self.field);
}
```

Comment: This makes sense to me, the contents of `vec` need to have the same lifetime as `self.field`, so when you later on access the contents of `vec` then the reference to the content and `self.field` still exists.

Comment: @user1307434 The _contents_ of `vec` do (the `&'a str`), but they're shared references so everything is fine. But the `vec` itself don't need, and when you force it to be you're inviting errors.